# I need to share cookies between 2 sub domains while I'm working on one of them

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cookies

I'm working on a project with a sub-domain from a parent domain "that I have no access to"
ex: "my-project.parent.com"

there is another project under the main domain "parent.com"

ex: "other-project.parent.com"

I need to share cookies with some data from my project with "Other-project".

I tried many solutions but It needs me to access the parent domain project but I only have access to "my-project"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without access to "parent.com" that will set a cookie for `.parent.com`